# Ruby "Gets" doesn't let me type input?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code on a Xubuntu VM. When I try to use gets, visual studio will say [running] as if waiting for my input, but it won't allow me to type. The code is as simple as

```
x = gets
```

or

```
x = gets.chomp
```

Neither would work.

I am typing in the output section, where I'd type in VS on my regular desktop, but it isn't working. Any help would be much appreciated, I'm a bit stuck with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Try executing your script through the terminal (even VScode's integrated terminal should do) as opposed to through VScode's run option

Comment: Thanks for that @OliverRobie. The terminal doesn't seem to recognise any Ruby commands, but maybe I'm using it wrong. Gets doesn't work on my regular desktop Visual Studio Code either. Thanks a lot for your help though, I'm sure I'm missing something really obvious.

Comment: On second inspection, running the script outside Visual Studio works fine. No clue why.

Comment: Any time. And awesome you got it to work! Sometimes IDE's integrated terminals get a bit messed up. Typically I find working with a regular terminal works best... having said that I can't deny that I'm using VScode's terminal as well